# fpm: rpm: /usr/bin/rpmsign: No such file or directory

Tags: rpm, packaging, fpm

When I run `fpm` with `--rpm-sign` I get the following error,

> rpm: /usr/bin/rpmsign: No such file or directory

I am using CentOS

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This error occurs because the utility `rpmsign` is something you have to install. The package you want is `rpm-sign`

You'll want to do

```
yum install rpm-sign
```